# Read values of checkboxes when the value has spaces in java /servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I have Check boxes in my Jsp who string value is not one word i.e two or three words:

```
<tr>
            <td> Change Password</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="admin" value="Change Password" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> Add User</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="admin" value="Add User" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Modify Workclass</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="admin" value="Modify Workclass" /></td>
        </tr>
```

In my servlet I am picking the values as such:

```
 String[] adminresources = request.getParameterValues("admin");
if (adminresources.length > 0) {
                for (String admin : adminresources) {
                    System.out.println(admin);
                }
            }
```

My Output Prints only the First Work of each value i.e:

```
Change
Add
Modify
```

I do not have the liberty to change the values as they are fetched from an external database (Not displayed in my example). How do I get the full values or what is it that I am doing wrong that I am getting only the first word?

**Edit**
Using Robby Suggestion I noticed the Jsp that Picks values from the database is not Quoted. i.e

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="admin" value=<%= (String) one.get(1)%> /></td>
```

I changed to:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="admin" value="<%= (String) one.get(1)%>" /></td>
```

everything now looks fine.

Comment: please check twice, it's looks like code you wrote is perfect some minor error somewhere else which you haven't post here..

Comment: Can you preprocess the values and replace ' ' with '%20' ? might do the trick

Comment: I'm going to guess that the actual values in your HTML are not quoted.

Comment: you may add  a `underscore` (_) between the text of `value` field and replace this `( _ )` with whitespace at `servlet`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Checking that in an instant. Good insight.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen You are damn right. The Jsp that receives values from database is not quoted. Thank I owe you.

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException Awesome! Problem solved. Yeah, not my first rodeo :)

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException Could you post the update part of your question as an answer, and accept it? Helps keep the site clean and easy to navigate.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen OK doing that in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Robby Cornelissen Suggestion that the Values from the database may not be quoted. I noticed that the JSP was like this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="admin" value=<%= (String) one.get(1)%> /></td>
```

so I changed it to this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="admin" value="<%= (String) one.get(1)%>" /></td>
```

This fixed the issues. Thank you.